# Concatenate multiple string / text fields some of which may have NULL values ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

I am trying to repeat the behavior of [this code from the ESRI website](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/08/30/concatenate/).

I want to replicate the output example in `ALL_Type` field, so that it concatenates a field but it deals (ignores) any that have NULL values.

Unfortunately this example no longer works at 10.2.2 because all example of NULL return a "None" text. Instead I just want a blank to show.

[image]

[image]

And here is the code.

```
   "*args" allows this routine to accept any number of field values.
# the values are passed as a Python tuple, essentially a
# non-editable list
#
def concat(*args):

  # Initialize the return value to an empty string,
  # then set the separator character
  #
  retval = ""
  sep = "_"

  # For each value passed in...
  #
  for t in args:
    # Convert to a string (this catches any numbers),
    # then remove leading and trailing blanks
    #
    s = str(t).strip()

    # Add the field value to the return value, using the separator
    # defined above
    #
    if s <> '':
      retval += sep + s

  # Strip of any leading separators before returning the value
  #
  return retval.lstrip(sep)
```

Comment: Try `if s <> '' and s is not None:`

Comment: Thanks I just tried your suggestion, i also tried the following but none of them worked   if (s <> '' and s is not None):              if s <> '' and s is not "None":

Comment: How about conditional `if t is not None:` before it converts t to a string `s = str(t).strip()` --- or `if s <>'' and s <> 'None'`:

Comment: yep that worked now with the 'None'  - it needed the quotations, as it is text - THANKS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
def concat(*args):
    sep = "_"

    nonnull_args = [str(arg).strip() for arg in args if arg]  # Filter NULLs
    good_args = [arg for arg in nonnull_args if arg]          # Filter blanks

    retval = sep.join(good_args)

    return retval
```

The args just get passed through a couple filters and joined by `sep` at the end.

Comment: just tested this and it works as well -many thanks!